# Empty array in string breaking deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I have a string of JSON that I'm trying to convert into a list. There is an empty array value which is breaking the deserialization (have tried removing it manually or changing to a number and it works). Was thinking I could try to replace the [] in the string, but is there a better way to work around this?

```
public class Tax
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
    public string PathOfTerm;
    public string Children;
    public string Level;
    public string RawTerm;
}

var exString = "[{\"Id\":\"12345\",\"Name\":\"aName\",\"PathOfTerm\":\"aTerm\",\"Children\":[],\"Level\":0,\"RawTerm\":null}]";
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var taxData = ser.Deserialize<List<Tax>>(exString);
```

Comment: Have you tried making your model reflect your JSON instead? It looks like `Children` should be an array (can't tell what kind here) rather than a string...

Comment: Yep thanks that was it. Didn't realize that couldn't be converted to a string

Comment: Okay, will post as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value is an array, but your field is a string. I suggest you make it an array (or list) of the appropriate type - we can't tell what that type would be from your JSON, but perhaps you want a string array?

I'd also suggest using properties instead of public fields.

(If you can move to Json.NET, I'd generally recommend that over `JavaScriptSerializer`, too...)